# Django REST with jwt + regular admin panel

Tags: django, rest, jwt

I've setup a basic django app using scaffolding which creates all those nice admin panels for free.

I want to expose a REST api so I've followed [this tutorial](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/12/19/how-to-use-jwt-authentication-with-django-rest-framework.html) to get it running and add JWT authentication through simplejwt. I have tested my rest auth endpoints, gotten a token and used that token to consume a secured rest endpoint.

The problem is -- as soon as I enable this auth scheme, the admin panel stops working. I can't login at all. Which I guess it makes sense considering I've changed the auth paradigm, but it kinda defeats the purpose of the scaffolding to lose all those free admin panels.

Is it possible to combine both jwt authentication for my REST services while keeping regular authentication scheme for my admin panel?

I want to do a public frontend through REST but keeping my backoffice within the same deployment as the backedn itself.

Comment: Which admin panel are you using? Django's default admin site doesn't use DRF so adding JWT tokens for REST auth should not interfere with django's admin site.

Comment: actually i think you are right, I dunno what happened yesterday that it wasnt working, but it is now.